# How to import PHPUnit reports with cascaded testsuites into Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, phpunit

Our PHPUnit report contains cascaded testsuites. This is not a problem for Sonarqube per se, but it becomes if the most inner testsuite does not containt a file attribute.

We are writing PHPUnit tests and are using data providers. This will lead to cascaded testsuites in the JUnit-style test report (--log-junit Flag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="" tests="5" assertions="64" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" time="14.915989">
    <testsuite name="Unit Tests" tests="5" assertions="64" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" time="1.486124">
      <testsuite name="Some\Path\ABCTest" file="/home/jenkins/some/path/ABCTest.php" tests="2" assertions="40" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" time="1.311815">
        <testcase name="test1" class="Some\Path\ABCTest" classname="Some.Path.ABCTest" file="/home/jenkins/some/path/ABCTest.php" line="346" assertions="27" time="1.108117"/>
        <testcase name="test2" class="Some\Path\ABCTest" classname="Some.Path.ABCTest" file="/home/jenkins/some/path/ABCTest.php" line="454" assertions="1" time="0.036422"/>
      </testsuite>
      <testsuite name="Another\Path\XYZTest" file="/home/jenkins/another/path/XYZTest.php" tests="3" assertions="24" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" time="0.174309">
        <testcase name="test3" class="Another\Path\XYZTest" classname="Another.Path.XYZTest" file="/home/jenkins/another/path/XYZTest.php" line="202" assertions="3" time="0.006831"/>
        <testsuite name="Another\Path\XYZTest::test4" tests="2" assertions="15" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" time="0.070885">
          <testcase name="test4 with data set &quot;dataset1&quot;" class="Another\Path\XYZTest" classname="Another.Path.XYZTest" file="/home/jenkins/another/path/XYZTest.php" line="259" assertions="5" time="0.046686"/>
          <testcase name="test4 with data set &quot;dataset2&quot;" class="Another\Path\XYZTest" classname="Another.Path.XYZTest" file="/home/jenkins/another/path/XYZTest.php" line="259" assertions="5" time="0.010488"/>
        </testsuite>
      </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

As you can see the testsuite "Another\Path\XYZTest::test4" is created because of the use of a data provider.

If Sonarqube is analyzing this report it is complaining that

```
"Test cases must always be descendants of a file-based suite, skipping [...]"
```

because the testsuite "Another\Path\XYZTest::test4" has no file attribute. Is there any possibility to

a) suppress the generation of the extra testsuite for data provider tests in the report

or

b) make Sonarqube more robust against these kind of reports?

BTW: Adding a file attibute to the testsuite "Another\Path\XYZTest::test4" will not fix the problem as Sonarqube fails with

```
"File can't be indexed twice"
```

error then.

Comment: the `"File can't be indexed twice"` error is a configuration problem. Set `sonar.tests` to be your tests path. If it is within your `sonar.sources` path, then also add your tests dir to `sonar.exclusions` - which will fix the double index issue. `sonar.tests` does not use `sonar.exclusions`, so it will continue being scanned for tests

Comment: see issue https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5004

Comment: Hi @Ole, have you found a solution to this problem, by any chance? I'm struggling with the exact same issue.